# Can I use the following phrase?

Tags: grammar

Can I say " This machine is used by Robert" or do I have to use the word "being"

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more context?  Neither is wrong, but they convey different meanings.  Please take a [tour] of the site and read through the [FAQ].

Comment: Both are grammatical but mean slightly different (and plausible) things. "This machine is used by Robert" the machine is habitually used (on a day to day basis) by Robert. The implication of saying such a thing is probably that no one is using the machine at the moment but Robert may come back soon to use it. "This machine is being used by Robert" means, right at this moment there is a person using the machine, and that person is Robert. The implication is that the speaker is talking to someone who can't recognize who the person is or doesn't know their name.

Comment: Related: [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/26083)

Comment: Present tense without progressive on an active predicate is generic -- habitual, repetitive.  The **real** present tense, which refers to the actual ongoing present, is the progressive construction in the present tense. Of course, this applies only to semantically active verbs, not states.

Comment: Does this make the difference clear? "Is the photocopier available?" "Yes, it's used by Robert but it's not being used by him at the moment".

Answer (score 1):

This machine is used by Robert is the passive voice of "Robert uses this machine."

When 'being' is used (like This machine is being used by Robert), it becomes the passive voice of "Robert is using this machine."

Accordingly, the meaning also changes. It is important to know where one should use active voice and passive voice.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That has been corrected.